# VS Code + Prettier not using printWidth setting?

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier, prettier-vscode

I'm trying to get Prettier to format my files with a `printWidth` of 80 chars (what I understand to be the default). However, even with my user settings configured:

`"prettier.printWidth": 80`

AND using a `.prettierrc` config in the project:

```
{
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "useTabs": false,
  "printWidth": 80
}
```

...nothing changes when I save a file (other settings are implemented, which makes me think there is a conflict somewhere).

Even the Prettier output in VS Code shows that it's pulling in the config:

```
["INFO" - 8:27:53 PM] Using config file at '/Users/username/Documents/whatever/.prettierrc'
["INFO" - 8:27:53 PM] Prettier Options:
{
  "filepath": "/Users/username/Documents/whatever/project/file.mdx",
  "parser": "mdx",
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "useTabs": false,
  "printWidth": 80
}
["INFO" - 8:27:53 PM] Formatting completed in 93.855083ms.
```

Comment: "other settings are implemented" -- what does that mean exactly?

Comment: @thorn̈ sorry that was poorly worded - other configurations in my settings are properly applied, just not printWidth

Comment: I guess you're looking for this option https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#prose-wrap.
`printWidth` is just a number, not something disableable.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that with `always` setting.

Answer (score 10):

You're formatting MDX, which is a variant of Markdown. Breaking text to respect the print width in Markdown is considered unsafe by default because this can affect some renderers sensitive to line breaks. That's why Prettier's option `proseWrap`([docs](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#prose-wrap)) defaults to `preserve`. Set it to `always` for Prettier to start wrapping text.